# Navigation Controller changes color and after that reverts back to original color when segueing back from a view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor

So im having this weird issue that only happening on an actual device, the behaivour of the navigation controller is working normally on the Simulator

[No issues in the simulator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-BIwxIFWto&feature=youtu.be)

but on the actual device this issue appears.

[Issues on an actual Device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htxMgE-QNdY)

Now, in the main view Controller im calling [self setupNavigationBar] in the ViewDidLoad method, the setupNavigationBar contains:

```
UIColor * mycolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:120.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:mycolor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle: (UIBarStyle)UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
//    [self.menuButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ap_Icons_Basketball_Lines.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the mapViewer viewDidLoad method contains this line

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

i cant see why this issue is happening only to this view controller, i have other view controllers that segues to a web view and there is no problem in changing colors.

Comment: Your videos are set to private.

Comment: Weird that it flashes but I'm not seeing a persistent colour change. I the flash you manually changing back?

Comment: no, its just doing that automatically :(